# I want to get timestamps for all photos in the camera roll

Tags: ios, camera, uiimagepickercontroller, alassetslibrary, photo-gallery

I'm guessing the App sandbox is the critical issue here.

UIImagePickerController will let users pick a single photo from camera roll, same with the Steroids/PhoneGap Camera API.

[ELCImagePickerController](https://github.com/B-Sides/ELCImagePickerController) supports multiple selection in a native App.

[ALAssetsLibrary](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) seems to be promising, but the PhotosByLocation sample project says, "Assets need to be synced to the device from iTunes to show up in the picker" which makes me think it doesn't give full access to the camera roll.

Is there an easy to get user permission to scan all the photos in the camera roll to extract and chart the photo timestamps? An html5 framerwork solution is perferred...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read the API docs again for [ALAssetsLibrary](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html), and discovered the following:

```
ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos - All the photos in the Camera Roll.

ALAssetsGroupAlbum - All the albums created on the device or synced from iTunes, 
   not including Photo Stream or Shared Streams
```

So I'm guessing that ALAssetsLibrary is indeed the Class I use to iterate through all photos in the Camera Roll. Can someone pls confirm that this is all I need to get access?

```
[ALAssetsLibrary authorizationStatus] == ALAuthorizationStatusAuthorized;
```